# How to make a query_builder out of raw sql

Tags: php, sql, symfony

I need help to change this code into a query builder in Symfony 5.

```
$em = $this->getEntityManager();
$query = "SELECT * FROM fizuser where roles::text LIKE  :role";
$statement = $em->getConnection()->prepare($query);
$statement->bindValue('role', '%'.$role.'%');
$statement->execute();
$result = $statement->fetchAll();
return $result;
```

This is what I've tried:

```
function (UserRepository $er) {
  return $er->createQueryBuilder('u')
  ->where("u.roles :: text like '%a%'");
```

However, I can't use "::" tag.

Comment: Your column name is really `roles::text`?

Comment: The column name is roles and the type of column is json

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with -

```php
return $this->createQueryBuilder('u')
            ->andWhere('u.roles LIKE :role')
            ->setParameter('role', '%'.'a'.'%')
            ->getQuery()
            ->getResult();
```

Comment: Unfotunatly i have an error:

SQLSTATE[42883]: Undefined function: 7 ERROR: operator does not exist: json ~~ unknown
LINE 1: ...ted AS activated_25 FROM fizuser f0_ WHERE f0_.roles LIKE $1

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to add some details, 
the column type in psql is json.
Using this type of query builder gives me error

```
SQLSTATE[42883]: Undefined function: 7 ERROR: operator does not exist: json ~~ unknown
LINE 1: ...ted AS activated_25 FROM fizuser f0_ WHERE f0_.roles LIKE $1
```